# AWS REST API v4, SignatureDoesNotMatch, wrong Signature using example values/algo steps

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hmac, sha256

Why am I getting different values for "Signature" from the example here (from which I copied values and algorithm steps)?

Input:

```
var YourSecretAccessKey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY';
var date = '20130524';

var signing_key = getSignatureKey(YourSecretAccessKey, date, 'us-east-1', 's3');

StringToSign: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20130524T000000Z
20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
3bfa292879f6447bbcda7001decf97f4a54dc650c8942174ae0a9121cf58ad04

var Signature = Crypto.HmacSHA256( signing_key, StringToSign );
```

Output

```
Signature: c4b97c8d906d49d5fb7a14479fc69b033cbf2d1b9bb67df6058ec8ab4714ee97
```

As you can see, the Signature result is different from the example from Amazon here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

```
Signature: aeeed9bbccd4d02ee5c0109b86d86835f995330da4c265957d157751f604d404
```

Maybe my getSignatureKey function isn't performing the Hmac.Sha256 functions correctly?

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {

   var hs = Crypto.HmacSHA256;
   var kSigning = hs(hs(hs(hs("AWS4" + YourSecretAccessKey,dateStamp),regionName),serviceName),"aws4_request");

   return kSigning;
}
```

I get this signing_key, fwiw:

```
//signing_key: 582cf07cc7ea5cd0a5c0a1f6422cf32eef38fdae7a4073d17ba0195cbf5c85ce
```

The example doesn't show the signing_key result, so I can't know if the signing_key is correct. What I know is the resulting Signature is not like in the example result.

The example url result will give "Request has expired", which is expected, but when using a current date, I get SignatureDoesNotMatch.

Something is wrong with the Signature generation.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html for an example of a correctly hashed signing key, and a download that includes the intermediate step results of the signing process for several test cases, and let us know what you find.

Comment: @mylord I'm encountering a similar problem with the updated Amazon S3 test suite examples (i.e., YYYYMMDD=20150830): my intermediate steps check out correctly based on the published intermediate values but the signature at the end of task #3 is incorrect.  Did you ever solve your problem, and can you share it here?  Thanks!